# JSONB Query Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have one table in postgres table and table structure is

`ID
Name
Details
Context 
CreatedDate`

Where as `Context` is `JSONB` field and `CreatedDate` is a `timestamp`

I am saving data in Context this way `{"trade": {"id": 102}, "trader": {"id": 100}}`

I am trying to select record from `Context` based on `trader` id and this is my query

```
 this.findAll({
    where: {
      context: {
        $contains: {
          trader: [{id: '100'}]
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

I tried nested keys as well but no result yeild.

```
   this.findAll({
        where: {
          'context.trader.id': {
            $eq: '100'
          }
        }
      })
```

Can you please suggest how I can select the records based on my structure.

In continuity to that how I can get records based on two statements like adding createdtime in this where clause